# Least Squares Estimators Derivation (Bi-variate)

Tags: statistics, regression

To derive least square estimators:

We have $SS(\alpha,\beta)= \sum(y_i-\alpha-bx_i)^2$ and find partials for each.
The answer I get is:

$\beta = \frac{\sum y_i-\bar{y}}{\sum x_i-\bar{x}}$,
but the book's solution "has an easier to work with form" $\beta = \frac{\sum (y_i-\bar{y})(x_i-\bar{x})}{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2}$.

What is the reasoning for writing it in such a way?

Edit: By taking partial derivatives with respect to $\alpha$ and setting equal to zero. I get $\alpha = \bar{y}-\beta\bar{x}$. When I did the partial derivative with respect to $\beta$, I get $-2(\sum y_i - \alpha - \beta x_i)x_i = 0,$ I reorganized terms distributed $x_i$ and got $\sum(y_i-\bar{y} )x_i = \beta \sum(x_i - \bar{x})x_i$ and cancelled the $x_i$ term to solve for $\beta$.

Comment: Can you show us how you get $\beta = \frac{\sum y_i-\bar{y}}{\sum x_i-\bar{x}}$?

Comment: Hi, added in a edit to show the work in deriving beta.

Comment: Does $x_i$ = $x_i - \bar{x}$? If so I don't see it. I assumed it was a simple cancellation and multiplication up and down by the same term.

Comment: See my answer. Do you understand now.

Comment: @Tangent You cannot cancel $(x_i-\overline x)$. Why should be $x_i=x_i-\overline x$ ? It only holds, if $\overline x=0$

Comment: Oh, I'm mistaken on my summation rules, I realize it sum of x over sum of x does not equal sum of x over x now. Thanks, but could you explain why sum $(x_i - \bar{x}) \bar{x}$ = 0? Is it because $\sum(x_i - \bar{x}) = 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your $\beta= \dfrac{\sum(y_i-\bar y)x_i}{\sum(x_i-\bar x)x_i} =\dfrac{\sum(y_i-\bar y)(x_i-\bar x)}{\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2}$

Since $\sum(y_i-\bar y)\bar x=0$ and $\sum(x_i-\bar x)\bar x=0$.

EDIT: $\sum(y_i-\bar y)\bar x= \bar x\sum(y_i- \bar y)\\=\bar x[\sum y_i-\sum \bar y]\\=\bar x[n\bar y-n\bar y]=0 $

Comment: Why are they both zero? Note: Just started learning regression.

Comment: @Tangent see my edit. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, so $\bar{x}$ can always be treated like some constant even though it is dependent on $x_i$ and be pulled out?

Comment: @Tangent Yes. it is.